# Moving the cursor inside brackets and intent when pressing RETURN

Tags: emacs

Let's see if I achieve to explain it. When I type this in emacs 24:

```
int foo() {|}
```

Note: | = Cursor

And press the Return key, I get the next output:

```
int foo() {
|}
```

So, my question is: how can I achieve the next behaviour?

```
int foo() {
    |
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `global-set-key` you should probably use something like `(define-key 'c++-mode-map ...`, but here's the basics.

```
(defun newline-and-push-brace ()
  "`newline-and-indent', but bracket aware."
  (interactive)
  (insert "\n")
  (when (looking-at "}")
    (insert "\n")
    (indent-according-to-mode)
    (forward-line -1))
  (indent-according-to-mode))

 (global-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-push-brace)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function that checks if you're in that situation and does what you want if you are, and otherwise just calls whatever the newline command for your major mode is, e.g.:

```lisp
(defun brackets-newline (point)
  (interactive "d")
  (setq next-char (char-before point))
  (if (and next-char 
       (char-equal next-char 123))
      ;; if we are sitting in front of a close bracket, do what you want
      (progn
        (newline)
        (newline)
        (previous-line)
        ;;call whatever "TAB" is in this mode
        (funcall (key-binding (kbd "TAB"))))
    ;; otherwise just insert a newline 
    (newline)))
```

Then bind this to `(kbd "RET")`

There may be a better way to do this using `defadvice` or some such, this seemed to work pretty well for me though.

Comment: The last funcall causes an infinite loop for me.

Comment: HAHA OH MAN, yeah you're right, I didn't actually bind this to "RET" and failed to consider that :P. Will correct.

Comment: =) The first thing that I thought when I read it was: "Cool! Emacs can tell what was previously bound to RET." And then I tested it =/

Comment: haha nope, just me being lazy. I think in order to get that you'd have to do some sort of hack where you stored the mode specific RET binding in a variable during the execution of a mode hook and then referenced that variable in this function. If local keybinds get run before mode hooks that won't work though; I don't know enough about what happens when a mode is triggered to say.